# preprocessing on the image to make line prominent before applying Probabilistic Hough Line Transform

Tags: java, c++, c, opencv, image-processing

I have tried the following methods in c++ opencv to accurately detect the lines before using probabilistic hough line transform in opencv:

1. Forming skeleton using erosion, dilation and subtraction
2. Morphological closing
3. Canny Edge detection
4. Gaussian Blur
5. Thresholding

I have used a lot of combinations and permutations of these methods as well as played around with the parameters of each of these functions as well as parameters of probabilistic hough line transform!

The skeleton method would have been ideal but it results a straight thick line being converted to shorter crooked lines

I am yet to get the ideal results. What improvements can be made or are there some methods which I have missed out on?

These are the images and the result of the skeleton:

[image: Orignal Image]

[image: Skeleton]

Comment: How about showing your input images and results so far?

Comment: @MarkSetchell ....I have edited the question and added the images

Comment: @MarkSetchell have I left out something? Why is no one answering?